# Trying to create a Listener pattern style class, observers won't get notified

Tags: java, design-patterns, listener

I'm now learning about the Listener or Observer-Observable design patter,
i tried to implement my own class using the supplied Java library `Observer` interface and `Observable` class.

My `Observable` subject is an empty class that `extends Observable`.

Here are my two `Observer` classes:

```
public class CatObserver implements Observer {
    private String status = "Sleeping...";
    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        System.out.println("Updated!");
        this.status = "Awake!";
    }

    public void getStatus(){
        System.out.println(status);
    }
}

public class DogObserver implements Observer {
    private String status = "Sleeping...";
    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        this.status = "Awake!";
    }

    public void getStatus(){
        System.out.println(status);
    }
}
```

Here is my `main` program:

```
public class Listener {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnimalSubject subject = new AnimalSubject();

        CatObserver mitsy = new CatObserver();
        DogObserver ozil = new DogObserver();

        mitsy.getStatus();
        ozil.getStatus();

        subject.addObserver(mitsy);
        subject.addObserver(ozil);

        synchronized (subject){
            subject.notifyAll();
        }

        mitsy.getStatus();
        ozil.getStatus();

    }
```

My output is 4 lines of "Sleeping...", when it should be 2 lines of "Sleeping..." and 2 lines of "Awake!".

When debugging it won't even go into the `update()` functions.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is only half done as you're not using the Observable class anywhere that we can see. The Observer/Observable interface/class pair don't work with Object's `notifyAll()`. Instead you must create a class that extends the Observable abstract class and then call the Observable's proper notify method, `notifyObservers(...)`, when appropriate.

Edit: I now see that you are using Observable but you don't show the code, but rather state that it's empty. Show your code, and make it "non-empty" where in fact you call the method above when its state changes.

Something like...

```
import java.util.*;

public class Listener {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      AnimalSubject subject = new AnimalSubject("My Dog");

      DogObserver ozil = new DogObserver();

      ozil.getStatus();

      subject.addObserver(ozil);

      subject.setStatus(Status.AWAKE);
      subject.setStatus(Status.EATING);

      ozil.getStatus();

   }

}

class DogObserver implements Observer {
   private Status status = Status.ASLEEP;

   @Override
   public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
      status = ((StatusEvent) arg).getNewValue();
      getStatus();
   }

   public void getStatus() {
      System.out.println("Status: " + status);
   }
}

class AnimalSubject extends Observable {
   private String name;
   private Status status = Status.ASLEEP;

   public AnimalSubject(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }

   public void setStatus(Status status) {
      Status oldValue = this.status;
      Status newValue = status;
      if (oldValue.equals(newValue)) {
         return;
      }
      this.status = status;
      StatusEvent event = new StatusEvent(this, oldValue, newValue);
      setChanged();
      notifyObservers(event);
   }

   public Status getStatus() {
      return status;
   }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }
}


enum Status {
   ASLEEP, AWAKE, EATING
}

class StatusEvent {
   private Object source;
   private Status oldValue;
   private Status newValue;

   public StatusEvent(Object source, Status oldValue, Status newValue) {
      this.source = source;
      this.oldValue = oldValue;
      this.newValue = newValue;
   }

   public Object getSource() {
      return source;
   }

   public Status getOldValue() {
      return oldValue;
   }

   public Status getNewValue() {
      return newValue;
   }

}
```

Comment: I created an empty class (`AnimalSubject`) which only extends the `Observable` class, i thought that's all i need in order to have an `Observable` class..

Comment: @argamanza: no, it can't be empty. It has to notify its internal list of observers when its state changes. And get rid of that `notifyAll()` business as that is not doing what you think it's doing and regardless, even if it were, it's in the wrong place. All notification calls should be from **within** the Observable. Again your code is half done.